# Is it possible to use the phrase 'Suit yourself' with other reflexive pronouns?

Tags: phrases, phrase-usage

Some dictionaries list the phrase in the generic form of **'Suit oneself'** (e.g. [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/suit%20oneself)). Although I have come across the phrase 'Suit yourself' many times, I haven't seen any example usage for other reflexive pronouns like themselves. Is it possible to use the phrase like 'Suit themselves' to mean 'I don't agree but they can do whatever they want'?

Comment: You can say that “they may suit themselves” without problems,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No: "suit themselves" is not a grammatical sentence.

*Suit* in "suit yourself" is in the imperative mood: it's telling your interlocutor to do something. You can only **tell** someone to do something if you are addressing them directly. The reflexive pronoun *yourself* refers to the person you're addressing.

With *themselves,* you are talking **about** people, not **to** them. So you can't use an imperative verb. You would need to say something like "They can suit themselves," using an indicative form.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I'm unable to upvote your answer because I don't have enough reputation. I hope somebody does it on behalf of me.